# Excel file accessed user names

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've created an Excel report file and placed it in my office shared folder some of my office colleges have accessed and and edited the  contents. How I can find the recently accessed username of that file...???

Comment: You might need some work to find that kind of information. See http://smallbusiness.chron.com/see-accessed-file-last-network-66995.html

Answer (score 3):

Excel 2010 and later has a [track changes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-22aea671-cac7-4fa3-845d-eeb23725bd15) feature that, if enabled, will show the author of any change in a shared workbook. I don't think that it can be used to track mere *access* but your question refers to users who have *accessed and edited* the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the "GetUserName()" function from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/161394) for years. Stick that in a new module, and then in the ThisWorkbook code you can use something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = GetUserName
    Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = Now()
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Then, when anyone opens the workbook, it will stick their username from the computer and the date/time into Sheet1 and keep a log of it.